# Access template's arguments with partial type knowledge

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have some code with deep C++ 11 variadic template's magic usage. I am using specialized classes to identify parts of template tree, which I am naming "tags". Each tag has unique number identifier.
I need to find a way how to access tag's identifiers

Here is some small example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned long ID, typename PARAM>
class tag_
{
    //getter for ID. Better to exclude it. If possible - move to external helper
    constexpr static unsigned long get_id() {return ID;}
    //PARAM is used in some functions of this class
};

//tag's declarations for future usage
template<typename PARAM>
using tag1 = tag_<1UL, PARAM>;
template<typename PARAM>
using tag2 = tag_<2UL, PARAM>;
template<typename PARAM>
using tag3 = tag_<3UL, PARAM>;

//helper class that can iterate TAGS
template <template<typename> class... TAGS>
struct helper
{};
template <template<typename> class TAG>
struct helper<TAG>
{
    static void print_tag(std::ostream& out)
    {
        out << std::string("Tag");
        out << TAG::get_id();  // Here I can't call: error: 'template<class> class TAG' used without template parameters
    }
};
template <template<typename> class TAG, template<typename> class... TAGS>
struct helper<TAG, TAGS...>
{
    static void print_tag(std::ostream& out)
    {
        out << std::string("Tag");
        out << TAG::get_id();  // Here I can't call: error: 'template<class> class TAG' used without template parameters
        out << std::string(", ");
        helper<TAGS...>::print_tag(out);
    }
};

//this class uses tags for some processing
template <template<typename> class... TAG_LIST>
class tagged
{
public:
    void test1(std::ostream& out)
    {
        out << std::string("This function works good");
    }
    void test2(std::ostream& out)
    {
        helper<TAG_LIST...>::print_tag(out);
    }
};

// this class is re-defined for some types of T
template<typename T, typename PARAM>
class usage
{
public:
    void test1(std::ostream& out)
    {
        details.test1(out);
    }
    void test2(std::ostream& out)
    {
        details.test2(out);
    }

    T details;
    PARAM params;
};

//endpoint
struct finish{};

//definition for future usage
template<template<typename> class T1, template<typename> class T2, template<typename> class T3, typename PARAM>
using multitag = usage<tagged<T1, T2, T3>, PARAM>;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // this way I am construction my objects tree
    multitag<tag1, tag2, tag3, tag1<tag2<tag3<finish>>>> tmp;
    tmp.test1(std::cout); // ok
    std::cout << std::endl;
    tmp.test2(std::cout);  //compile error. I want to get "Tag1, Tag2, Tag3" printed
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: 'TAG::get_id()' doesn't work since TAG is not a complete type. As per you definition of tag1/tag2/tag3 you need to provide it with a template parameter called PARAM for whatever reason you have put it there for. Just by making a change to 'TAG<int>::get_id()' and making the member function 'get_id' public, I was able to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
multitag<tag1, tag2, tag3, tag1<tag2<tag3<finish>>>> tmp;
```

This is your definition for `tmp`, you just pass in `tag1`, which is a template type alias

```
template<typename PARAM>
using tag1 = tag_<1UL, PARAM>;
```

however its template parameter `PARAM` isn't provided.
So when you want to use it,

```
out << TAG::get_id()
```

You should give it a parameter, for example

```
out << TAG<dummy>::get_id();
```

`dummy` can be anything, for example,

```
class dummy{};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb1d924dc3d5b774

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The idea of using any type (even void works) instead of the PARAM solves the problem in my case.  I don't have an access to the right PARAM struct in my function and can't pass it as parameter. This way producess less clear code, but it is acceptable for me

Answer (score 1):

The closest what you can get is to declare a specialization for each `tagX`:

```
template <template <typename> class TAG> struct tag_id;

template <> struct tag_id<tag1> : std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 1UL> {};
template <> struct tag_id<tag2> : std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 2UL> {};
template <> struct tag_id<tag3> : std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 3UL> {};
```

```
out << tag_id<TAG>{};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfbef9917060966c)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks like this code is preferrable as it is designed better. But in my case I prefer using some extra structure as PARAM argument as I don't want to declare extra specialization for each tag